# Send GPS data to a web service every 10 minutes

Tags: android, web-services

Hi im developing a android app that get your current location and send it to a web service even if the user minimize the app , the part of getting the location and connecting with mi WB is working the question is how can send the data every 10 min and how keep sending that data even if the user minimize the app , i had research a little and many ppl say i should use android service or use a timer im really new at android and this is something confusing for me hope u can help me with a example

Comment: On modern devices you can't.  Doze mode will break that.  You can get every 15ish minutes at best.  But the right answer for anything periodic is to use JobScheduler to schedule a repeating job, get the data you need, then send it to the server all during the job.

Comment: will JobScheduler work in devices under API 21 ??

Comment: Workscheduler, which wraps job scheduler, will

Comment: you can use WorkManager https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/